# pandas- selecting dataframe columns corresponding to specific indices

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a Dataframe:

```
>>> cs
Out[75]: 
     0   1  2   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10    11    12    13
130  AB  Y  C  CI  D  G  R  J  S  T  N  None  None  None
143  B   Y  C  CI  D  G  R  J  S  T  N  None  None  None
146  B   Y  C  M   D  G  Q  J  S  T  N  None  None  None
324  B   Y  C  CI  D  G  R  J  S  T  N  None  None  None
327  B   Y  C  CI  D  G  R  J  S  T  N  None  None  None
```

And a dataframe of specific column ids:

```
>>> r
Out[76]: 
       0
130 8.00
143 2.00
146 2.00
324 8.00
327 6.00
```

I want to select value from cs corresponding to the column id specified in r

So the output desired is:

```
>>> out
    Out[76]: 
           0
    130 S
    143 C
    146 C
    324 S
    327 R
```

This is currently failing:

```
>>> cs.iloc[:,r]
Out[77]: 
     0
130  AB
143  B
146  B
324  B
327  B
```

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `lookup`

```
df.lookup(r.index,r['0'].astype(int).astype(str))
Out[106]: array(['S', 'C', 'C', 'S', 'R'], dtype=object)
```